# scipy's solve_ivp returns erroneous results for a stiff differential equation

Tags: python, scipy, stiffness

I'm using scipy's *solve_ivp* for solving a stiff differential equation. I'm using method **BDF** for solving the same.
I have already used MATLAB's **ode23s** and I'm getting correct results in MATLAB.
However, solve_ivp returns the wrong results. The problem might be in computing **X**.
My code is :

```
X0=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0])
swd=0
start =timer()
for k in range(0,100):
    

    tspan=[k*(1e-4), (k+.7)*(1e-4)]
    tspan1=[(k+.7)*(1e-4), (k+1)*(1e-4)]
    
    swm=1
    sol=solve_ivp(conv,tspan,X0,method='BDF')
    TT=sol.t
    YY=sol.y
    
    swm=0
    sol1=solve_ivp(conv,tspan1,YY[:,-1],method='BDF')
    TT1=sol1.t
    YY1=sol1.y
    X0=YY1[:,-1]
    plt.plot(TT,YY[0,:],'r')
    plt.plot(TT,YY[1,:],'b')

end=timer()
print(end-start)
```

for the function defined as

```
def conv(t,X):
    
    global swd
        if (swd==0) or (swd==1 and X[0]>0):
            
            Xdot = A11.dot(X).reshape(6,1) + B11.dot(U)
            swd=1
        else:
            
            Xdot = A10.dot(X).reshape(6,1) + B10.dot(U)
            swd=0
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(Xdot))
```

The matrices **A**'s are *6*6* , **B**'s are *6*2* resp. **X** is *6*1*. One of the **X** values is computed incorrectly and then the whole plot is returned incorrect. Just the plot for the first cycle is returned correctly.
**Details**: The given code is of a boost converter. **swm** and **swd** are the switching states of the MOSFET and diode respectively.
As far as I could debug, the diode switches correctly for the first cycle. But for the second and other cycles, the diode doesn't switch off and just remains on.

Comment: Are you asking about the differences between methods, or are you asking how to debug the code?

Comment: I needed help in debugging. I've edited the post to further clarify my point.

Comment: Try rewriting this without globals. Instead consider passing these values as paramters to your ODE function

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. Help really appreciated.